# Select records between yesterday and today

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have trying to implement a simple SQL query that gets records between today's fixed timing (e.g. 18:00) and yesterday's fixed timing (e.g. 18:00).

```
SELECT * FROM [Table]
WHERE [Table].[Date Time] > Now()-1;
```

However, this will return all records between today's current timing and yesterday's.

Is there a way to return records within specified timings?

Edit:
I tried this query, but its throwing syntax error.

```
SELECT * FROM [Table]
WHERE [Date Time] BETWEEN FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, - 1, NOW()) AS DATETIME) + FORMAT('18:00:00' AS TIME) AND FORMAT(NOW() AS DATETIME) + FORMAT('18:00:00' AS TIME);
```

Any help?

Comment: add more details . like example

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale If let's say right now is **17-Nov-16 19:00:00**, I would like to return all records from [Table] between **16-Nov-16 18:00:00** to **17-Nov-16 18:00:00**. Will it be possible? If I use `Now()-1`, it will return between **16-Nov-16 19:00:00** and **17-Nov-16 19:00:00**

Comment: @Fionnuala It still returns me a syntax error. `SELECT * FROM [In process analysis result]
WHERE [Date Time] BETWEEN FORMAT(DATEADD("h", -25, NOW()) AS DATETIME) + FORMAT('18:00:00' AS TIME) AND FORMAT(NOW() AS DATETIME) + FORMAT('18:00:00' AS TIME);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the variable date values and the fixed time value.

Date/Time constants can be fickle with all the different local formats. With `TimeSerial` we can avoid this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Table].[Date Time] Between Date()-1 + TimeSerial(18,0,0) 
                              And Date()   + TimeSerial(18,0,0)
```

---

(First suggestion, works with German date format)

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Table].[Date Time] Between Date()-1 + #18:00:00# And Date() + #18:00:00#
```

The query designer may automatically change this into

```
Between Date()-1 + #12/30/1899 18:00:00# And Date() + #12/30/1899 18:00:00#
```

`1899-12-30` is "Date zero" in Access.

Comment: Thanks. My [Date Time] column is defined as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` I used your query and it did not have any syntax error, but it does not show any records. In my database, I have **17/10/2016 6:00:00 PM**, **17/10/2016 2:00:00 PM**, **17/10/2016 10:00:00 AM**, **16/10/2016 7:00:00 PM**. But it does not show any of these...

Comment: @YongXiangSoh: The column format should not have any influence. Perhaps try `#6:00:00 PM#` instead of `#18:00:00#`.

Comment: @YongXiangSoh: Or with `TimeSerial` for date format independence, see edit.

Comment: @Andre I tried `SELECT * FROM [In process analysis result]
WHERE [Date Time] Between Date()-1 + #12/30/1899 6:00:00 PM# And Date() + #12/30/1899 6:00:00 PM#` but it still does not return any records. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: @MtwStark: Did you read the question? It asks for records between 18:00 (prev. day) and 18:00 (today). Not between 00:00 and 23:59.

Comment: sorry, I based myself on a comment he post on my answer talking only of dates and not time. pardon

Comment: I have tried, but you should edit the answer or I will be not able to undo. just make an irrilevant edit..

Comment: Thanks to both for the help. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Table].[Date Time] between #16/11/2016 14:00:00# and #17/11/2016 14:00:00#
```

but pay attention to MDY - DMY date format..

I prefer [ODBC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190234(v=sql.90).aspx)C format to avoid problems:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Table].[Date Time] between {ts'1970-01-12 14:00:00' } and {ts'1975-01-12 14:00:00'}
```

Comment: Yes, it is something similar. But I don't wish to hardcode the datetime. If today is 17-Nov-16, it will query between 16-Nov-16 and 17-Nov-16. If tomorrow is 18-Nov-16, it will query between 17-Nov-16 and 18-Nov-16.

Comment: look at mine other answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
            declare
                    @StartDate DATE = NULL,
                    @EndDate DATE = NULL

            SELECT * FROM [Table]       
             WHERE
             CAST( [Date Time] AS DATE) >= CAST( ISNULL(@StartDate, '') AS DATE) 
             AND CAST( [Date Time] AS DATE) <= CAST( ISNULL(@EndDate, '') AS DATE)
```

or simply put date into @StartDate and @EndDate.

Comment: That is an example for SQL Server. SQL is a generic tag, and this one is labelled MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to first declare a variable for todays date at 18.00 and then compare your date to that, in Access you can make use of the TimeValue() function:

```
Dim Time18
Time18 = TimeValue("18:00")
```

Then you can compare your date to that and one day back:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table]
WHERE (
    (DateValue([Table].[Date Time]) = DateValue(Now() - 1) AND 
     TimeValue([Table].[Date Time]) >= Time18) OR
    (DateValue([Table].[Date Time]) = DateValue(Now() AND 
     TimeValue([Table].[Date Time]) <= Time18))
```

Comment: That is SQL Server, not MS Access.

Comment: @Fionnuala Are you able to help on this?

Answer (score 0):

use date() instead of now()

suppose today is 17nov (any time),

if you need records of yesterday 16nov (00:00 -> 23:59) you must use date()-1 as lower bound and date() as upper bound

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Table].[Date Time] between date()-1 and date()
```

if you need records of today 17nov (00:00 -> 23:59) you must use date() as lower bound and date()+1 as upper bound

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Table].[Date Time] between date() and date()+1
```

this is the simple version and it has a little problem with boundaries, the correct filter should be (for yesterday)

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Table].[Date Time] >= date()-1 [Table].[Date Time] < date()
```

or, for today:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Table].[Date Time] >= date() [Table].[Date Time] < date()+1
```

Comment: Thanks. Although it's not what I am looking for, but appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query for SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table]
WHERE DATEADD(HH, 18, CAST(CAST([Table].[Date Time] AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) > DATEADD(HH, 18, CAST(CAST(Now() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))-1;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am using MS Access. Is there some difference?

Comment: I do not have much idea about MS Access. You will need to change the Cast functions in MS Access to first remove time part and convert it to datetime and add the hours.